# Calendar left and right click arrows of months enable and disable based on certain dates in android

Tags: android

[image][image]

I have a calendar code where at the top of the page we have two years mentioned. 
Left side prev year and right side current year
So once the user opens the calendar the current year, date and month are shown default on the calendar.
For the calendar, both sides left and right arrow is there to go to next and previous months.

For ex: if we have 2017 and 2018, As per the req, if the user selects 2017 Jan, then the left arrow should be disabled. And if the user clicks right arrow the user should be able to go till December 2017 and after that, the right arrow should be disabled.
And then when the user clicks 2018, and move to Jan 2018 then the left arrow should be disabled. And again the right arrow of the month should be enabled only till the current month.
I tried in different ways but not able to disable the click upto the certain month.

```
//next arrow click for showing next month
nextMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

   if (month > 11) {//checking the month
     month = 1;
     year++;
   } else {
   month++;
   }
   setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
   }
   });

//prev arrow click to show prev month
    prevMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (month <= 1) {//checking the month
        month = 12;
        year--;
    } else {
    month--;
    }

    setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                        }
   });
```

Any help will be really thankful

Comment: probably use set max date and min date options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update the current time in `calendarMy` object using  below code and check the current month and year**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calendarMy = Calendar.getInstance();

nextMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

   if (month > 11) {//checking the month
     month = 1;
     year++;
   } else {
   month++;
   }

   //update current time
    calendarMy.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
    calendarMy.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);

    disableButton();

   setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
   }
   });

//prev arrow click to show prev month
    prevMonth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (month <= 1) {//checking the month
        month = 12;
        year--;
    } else {
    month--;
    }

    //update current time
     calendarMy.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
    calendarMy.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);

    disableButton();


    setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
                        }
   });
```

**Here i have added two condition for checking first month of last year and current month of running year**

```
public void disableButton()
   {

   // condition for checking first month of last year
     if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) != (calendarMy.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && calendarMy.get(Calendar.MONTH) == 0) {
            //disable left button
        }
        // condition for checking current month
        else if (calendarMy.get(Calendar.YEAR) == (calendarMy.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == calendarMy.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {

            //disable right button
        }else{
        // enable both button
        }


   }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. I have added the changes..in disableButton method in first if condition, calendarMy.get(Calendar.MONTH) == 0 it is showing in place of 0 must be one of: Calendar.sunday,Calendar.monday...can you tell me in place of 0 i need to add current day?

Comment: Hi, i have attached the imagein the question..can you  please let me know in place of 0 i need to add the current day in calendar?

Comment: have you import class `java.util.Calendar` or any other Calendar class

Comment: @Amrutha you can also use  `Calendar.JANUARY` intent of `0`

Comment: Thanks a lot..i have used this logic and able to perform the clicks based on the condition

Answer (score 1):

Just Pass start month in `myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(ActivityNewGroup.this, date,
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, i passed as  if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) != (calendarMy.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && Integer.toString(calendarMy.get(Calendar.MONTH)) == "January") {

Comment: myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)==Calendar.JANUARY try this bro